# Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.7

Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified[image]

How can I fixed this thing?
I been trying to reinstall mysqlserver 5.5 / 5.7 and workbench countless of time. But I still not able to fix this issue.

Comment: you may have to specify the path for ini/cnf file through to  Manage Server Connections -- > System profile --> Configuration file